# Color bar missing in ggplot legend, Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: r, ggplot2, rdp

I'm running R version 3.0.1 and ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1 on a Windows machine and getting aberrant behavior from color bar legends -- the legend labels appear but the color bar mysteriously does not.

For example, if I run the following code:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point()
```

I get this plot:
[image]

whereas on my other machine (a Mac running R version 2.15.2 and ggplot 0.9.3.1) the same code gives me this:
[image]

The behavior seems to apply only to color bars for continuous numerical variables -- legends for discrete factors appear as expected. I've tried reinstalling ggplot2. Anybody have thoughts on what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: What version of R and ggplot2 are you running? Have you tried reinstalling ggplot2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, and a working solution, [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-base-package-grid-does-not-output-raster-image-td4672188.html). It's an issue with color rendering when accessing a server via Remote Desktop, and can be fixed in host settings.

Comment: A partial solution, in case increasing the color depth of remote desktop is not an option, is to add 

+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5)))


(or something similar with "color") to the ggplot object. That replaces the continuous scale by a discrete one with a subset of the colors shown, which may be good enough for exploratory work. (For saving, I found using the cairo print option solved the problem.)