# Do ggplot-s depend on last desktop session properties?

Tags: windows, r, ggplot2

I have a couple of `Rscript`s running as scheduled jobs on a remote winXP server's task scheduler, producing some html pages which include plots [like this one](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram-40.png). See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414579/color-bar-missing-in-ggplot-legend-windows-remote-desktop).

I have noticed that when I am connected locally and run the job, the plots are ok. So when the jobs run on their own (but only if my last login has been done locally). However, if my last login -before the jobs execution- was through a remote desktop connection (16bit color quality) -no matter what I did in that session- the jobs that run afterwards do not produce those plots (in the html pages) correctly. And I am talking about plots with `guide_colorbar()` like the one in the link. Specifically, the gradient bar in the legend does not appear at all (I can see the legend title, the numbers, the ticks but only the color of the background, in place of the gradient color bar).

It is like R (or ggplot) somehow keeps some properties from the last desktop session and accordingly renders or not that colorbar (at least this is what I can figure out from the tests I have performed). Can you think of a solution?

P.S. The same jobs produce some pdfs (by weaving .rnw files) with similar plots, which do not have any problem.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 Patched (2014-05-24 r65737)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
 [1] datasets  grDevices splines   graphics  stats     grid      tcltk     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] markdown_0.6.3     knitr_1.6          fBasics_3010.86    timeSeries_3010.97 timeDate_3010.98   MASS_7.3-33        RODBC_1.3-10       car_2.0-20        
 [9] sos_1.3-8          brew_1.0-6         reshape2_1.4       scales_0.2.4       ggplot2_1.0.0      svSocket_0.9-57    TinnR_1.0-5        R2HTML_2.2.1      
[17] Hmisc_3.14-4       Formula_1.1-1      survival_2.37-7    lattice_0.20-29   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cluster_1.15.2      colorspace_1.2-4    digest_0.6.4        evaluate_0.5.5      formatR_0.10        gtable_0.1.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26
 [8] munsell_0.4.2       nnet_7.3-8          plyr_1.8.1          proto_0.3-10        RColorBrewer_1.0-5  Rcpp_0.11.1         stabledist_0.6-6   
[15] stringr_0.6.2       svMisc_0.9-70       tools_3.1.0
```

**UPDATE** (network administrator's comments)

*I ‘m not an R programmer but I’m a system programmer – technician and co worker to George Dontas. Having seen the above problem i have to comment the following. Remote desktop is for administrative purposes ONLY, There is no reason to resolve a case causing problem to a domain (traffic) making sessions heavier than necessary with resolution and or color depth…. The problem is for sure related to R, Desktop Sessions, and Screen adjustments… As George said his job is running on schedule on a remote server…and is running fine if the last desktop session (my term) is local to the server…... … If he connects (without doing anything) to the said server with remote desktop for a few seconds the problem appears…when the scheduled job runs…even if the remote session is closed for a long time…. R must be checking something in relation to the last desktop session on the job running machine …Does anyone have an answer to that..???*

Comment: How do you save these plots? Do you use `ggsave` or "natively" using `png()` (or some other device)?

Comment: I knit2html some .rmd files. - I should have said that :-)

Comment: No... because winxp remote desktop is up to 24bit any way...(tested in 3 terminals)

Comment: What happens if you set `raster = FALSE` in `guide_colorbar()`?

Comment: Very good idea! (I have set it in the second plot). That seems to be an acceptable compromise. You can post it as an answer. https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/576x720q90/903/OyDKVw.png

Answer (score 4):

Raster graphics is not available in some environment.
The colorbar guide of `ggplot2` provides both raster and non-raster version.

Try `guide_colorbar(..., raster = FALSE)` if you failed to draw a colorbar.
The default behavior is `raster = TRUE`.

Comment: And to see whether the current machine supports `rasterImage()` , check `dev.capabilities()`, using something like this: `local({dev.new(); on.exit(dev.off()); dev.capabilities()[["rasterImage"]]=="yes"})`.